# Dialog box not appearing after button click in javascript,php,ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dialog

I have Add Widget button and on click i want to display dialog box in which i have select box and save button. But after on click on Add widget button my dialog box is not appearing. I have by default configuration for button. And when i click on Add widget button and check on firebug my button event is firing properly but dont know where i making a small mistake as my dialog box not appearing.I used ajax call to display the dialog box.Here is jsfiddle without ajax call and its running fine:[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tchwk/185/) But i have to pass the widget ID that i am getting through Ajax and why the dialog box not appearing while using ajax dont know.
Here is my php code:

dashboard.php

```
$page['button'] = array(
    1 => array( 'Save','pfeil2r','',"'#'",'','','savewidgetId'),
    );
<table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td id="widget">   
                <br /><br/>       

<div id="output"></div>

<div id="overlay" class="web_dialog_overlay"></div>

<div id="dialog" class="web_dialog">
   <table style="width: 100%; border: 0px;" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
         <td class="web_dialog_title">Widget</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
         <td colspan="2" style="padding-left: 15px;">
            <b>Add Widget</b>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="2" style="padding-left: 15px;">
             <div id="widgets"> ';
              while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_results)){
                $widget=$row['ID'];
                $widget_name=$row['name']; 
              $html .= '
                 <select name="addwidgets" id="addwidgets" >
                         <option value='.$widget.'>'.$widget_name.'</option>                  
                </select>';
              }  
             $html .= '</div>

         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
            '.CreateButton($page['button']).'
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

dashboard.js

```
function getaddwidget()
    {
            $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/dashboard.php",
        dataType : 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: {'aktion' : 'add-new-widget'},
        success: function(data){
            $('#widget').html(data.html);                       
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert('error');
            //$('#news').html(data.html);
        }
      });
}   

function saveaddwidget()
    {
        var widgets = $('#widgets select[name="addwidgets"]').val();
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/dashboard.php",
        dataType : 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: {'aktion' : 'save-add-widget','widget':widgets},
        success: function(data){
            $('#widget').html(data.html);

        },
        error: function(data){
            alert('error');
            //$('#news').html(data.html);
        }
      });
}   


     $("#widget .butt-rahmen").click(function (e){
     if($(this).attr('id') == 'addwidgetId')
      {
         ShowDialog(false);
         e.preventDefault();
         getaddwidget();
       }
      });     

      $("#widget .butt-rahmen").click(function (e){
      if($(this).attr('id') == 'saveaddwidgetId')
      {
         HideDialog();
         e.preventDefault();
         saveaddwidget();
       }
      }); 

   function ShowDialog(modal)
   {
      $("#overlay").show();
      $("#dialog").fadeIn(300);     
   }

   function HideDialog()
   {
      $("#overlay").hide();
      $("#dialog").fadeOut(300);
   }
```

Comment: well your td id="widget" seems like it will all be overwritten by your ajax function for one....but besides that.  Are you sure you aren't meaning to append() to #widgets, as opposed to html() to #widget?

Comment: when i click on button i can see in firebug and the select box and ynd save button is appering there but why dialog box is not displaying i dont why...yes i am sure to apend to #widget

Comment: This might sound like a silly question, but what about `php` tags? Did you removed them on purpose of this question?

Comment: man i cant post my complete code i only post the necessory code required here...

Comment: Please check the updated question...i have added fiddle also

Comment: well that fiddle isnt using the same wierd nested td structure.  Also you seem to be filling the #output div whereas in the above code youre filling the #widget TD.  Perhaps you should be filling the #output fiv?? $("#output").html("<b>Widget: </b>" + widgets);

Comment: I get it now... I know it's off topic, but have you considered using templating engine or MVC? Having html in variables is real pain (I'm talking about `$html .= '(...)';` part). Just sayin...

Answer (score 0):

Web Forms and j-Query User interface's dialog plug-in don't work well together. This is because the elements used for the dialog box get taken out of the page DOM and put inside a new element. What's more than likely happening here is that your controls are being removed from the form, so hitting the submit button won't do anything.